# ACF permission for users to download the file

Tags: wordpress, file, download, advanced-custom-fields, uploading

I am working on file sharing system where a user is able to upload a file to their account.

Now the uploading part works. I made it so it uploads the file into a specific directory based on the user_nicename and the user_id

Example:

```
https://site.nl/wp-content/uploads/useruploads/[user_nicename][user_id]/file.pdf
```

So now I was thinking to rewrite the URL when a user clicks on the file to a download.php file which checks if the user is the correct user.

.htaccess:

```
# Disable directory listing
Options -Indexes

# Rewrite requests to /wp-content/uploads/useruploads/ to download.php
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/useruploads/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/Child%20Theme/file-access/download.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now the main problem is I am getting a permission error

My second inquiry is whether this is deemed safe. or should there be more authentication or should I do this in a complete different way?

Answer (score 0):

Add htaccess in your useruploads folder, to redirect user to download.php file, where you can check, if the user is the correct user..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /download.php?path=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I am pretty new to this so, When adding this code to my .htaccess the user doesn't have permissions "You do not have permission to access this content." What would be the correct way to handle this now. (keeping safety in mind.)